# Asynchronous script not accessible

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am loading a script that I created asynchronously to help prevent slowing down the site. I'm unable to call the class Class.track({"some_param":"some_data"}) due to it not being available yet. How can I achieve asynchronous loading and having the ability to call the class?

The code for loading in the js is below, it's occurring before the closing body tag and the Class.track is getting called below it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function() {
        function async_load(){
            var api_id = "XXXXXXXXX";
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.type = 'text/javascript';
            s.async = true;
            s.src = 'https://site.com/script.js?id=' + api_id;
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
         }
    if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent('onload', async_load);
    else
        window.addEventListener('load', async_load, false);
    })();

    Class.track("page_view", {"page":"plans"});
</script>
```

**Edit**

Took the comment from Dan and the answer from TJ and decided to modify it, below is what I came up with, hoping this will help someone else.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _Class = new function(){
        var items = [];

        this.track = function(type, params){
            params = params || {};
            items.push({"type":type, "params":params});
        }

        this.get = function(){
            return items;
        }

    };

    var Class = _Class;

    (function() {
        function async_load(){
            var api_id = "XXXXXXXXX";
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.type = 'text/javascript';
            s.async = true;
            s.src = 'https://site.com/script.js?id=' + api_id;
            s.onload = function(){
                var items = _Class.get();
                Class.trackBatch(items);
            };
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
         }
    if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent('onload', async_load);
    else
        window.addEventListener('load', async_load, false);
    })();

    Class.track("page_view", {"page":"plans"});
</script>
```

Comment: you can make a fake Class.track that logs incoming calls until the real one shows up, just make sure to grab the calls before clobbering window.Class... personally, i prefer polling in a self-executing function that would return a setTimeout(arguments.callee); if self.Class is falsy...

Comment: @dandavis thanks, I am actually using what you said + what TJ's answer was. Rather than using the setTimeout, I am using the onload. Pretty cool stuff!

Answer (score 2):

In all major current browsers, the `script` element's `onload` can be used:

```
s.onload = function() {
    /* ...this is called when the script is loaded, so `Class` should
       be available...
    */
    Class.track("page_view", {"page":"plans"});
};
```

In older versions of IE, you had to use `onreadystatechange` instead and check that the element's `readyState` property was the string `"complete"`.

Alternately, of course, you can use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to poll for a global symbol (`Class`, in your case, I suspect) you create (via `typeof`, e.g. `if (typeof Class === "undefined") { /* ...schedule another check in a few milliseconds... */ }`).

Comment: Thanks for this, would this be the best route if I loaded the script and tried calling Class.track() anywhere throughout the page?

Comment: @BrianPutt: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Using `onload` (`onreadystatechange` on older IE) is the best way to know when your script has been loaded. Polling is also an option, but tends to involve more lag time.

Comment: Trying to replicate how google analytics works, you load in the GA code and then you can use ga.track() anywhere throughout the page, hoping this makes sense as I am fairly new to the JS world

Comment: If you're loading the code **asynchronously**, you can't rely on it being loaded anywhere except in the load callback or something called from it.

Comment: Ok, I think I will combine your answer plus what Dandavis commented. Will create a small version of the class to track the data and process it before it gets replaced. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @BrianPutt: (Had to disappear) Oddly, I was thinking much the same thing: A small inline script to queue things up, and the main script to deal with them. Sounds like a plan.

Comment: i've turned document.write into a queue to hijack performance-killing ads (re-injecting them async later). to me, this is one of JS's best qualities: malleability.